# react-native deep-link param doesn't disappear

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, url-scheme

I'm using Depp-Link in react-native

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links
(react-navigation v5)

If I click

My config is

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    HomeStack: {
      initialRouteName: 'HomeMain',
      screens: {
        HomeMain: {
          path: '',
        }
      }
    },
    ProductStack: {
      initialRouteName: 'ProductMain',
      screens: {
        Ranking: 'ranking/:category?/:order?',
      }
    },
    // NotFound: '*',
  }
}
const linking: LinkingOptions = {
  prefixes: ['myapp://'],
  config,
};
```

And Ranking Screen is

```
const Ranking = ({ route }: Props) => {
  console.log(' route ', route.params);

  return (
    <View>
      ...
    </View>
  );
};
```

When I write "myapp://ranking?category=aa&order=bb" in Safari (iOS simulator),
It works.

But I enter "Ranking" without DeepLink, route.params does not disappear and remains.
I want to apply this only when it comes in via deep link.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
  prefixes: ["https://coingiftcard.com"],
  config: {
    screens: {
      deeplink: {
        path: 'deeplink/id',
      },
    },
  },
}
Make deeplink url:
https://example.com/deeplink/details?token=uygiuhiuhpuihpiuyiuhuihhiluhiu

Access token from component:
this.props.route.params.token

result will be =uygiuhiuhpuihpiuyiuhuihhiluhiu
```

Comment: Please try to explain what you did / edited

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

u can use Linking react-native addEventlistener in the component and check it is opened in deeplinking in componentDidMount

```
const Ranking = ({ route }: Props) => {
 componentDidMount(){
        Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handledeeplink);
}

handledeeplink = async (event) => {
        let url = new URL(event.url);
         console.log(url );// in this u will get url here u can get params        
    }
    
  return (
    <View>
      ...
    </View>
  );
};
```